# Tableview is not displaying the NewsFeed using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

News feed are not shown in table viewcontroller.BuyerSocialPage that is linked with Newsfeed Viewcontroller has BuyerSocialPage.h file

```
@interface BuyerSocialPage : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation BuyerSocialPage

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.tableView.delegate=self;
    UINib * firstNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BSPFirstCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:firstNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BSPFirstCell"];
    UINib * secondNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BSPSecondCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:secondNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BSPSecondCell"];
    UINib * thirdNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BSPThirdCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:thirdNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BSPThirdCell"];
    UINib * fourthNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BSPFourthCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:fourthNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BSPFourthCell"];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self getBuyerSocialPage];

    if (self.revealViewController) {
        [_sidebarButton addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }


}
-(void)getBuyerSocialPage {

    }

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    int row = (int)indexPath.row;
    if (row == 0) {

        return 324;
    }
    else if (row == 1)
    {
        return 152;
    }
    else if (row == 2)
    {
        return 152;
    }
    else
    {
        return 152;
    }
}



@end
```

After login you will see home screen. From side menu bar at the top select the "news feed" and it should display the news feed.but it is not displaying newsfeeds.Api is running correctly on postman

How I can get news feed in the table view ?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page Number is missing in your url `&pageno=1`.

Your url looks like this:
http://api.shoclef.com/api/NewsFeed?user_id=1164

It should be like this:
http://api.shoclef.com/api/NewsFeed?user_id=1164&pageno=1

try this in you API Manager class. Working fine for me.

```
 NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@NewsFeed?user_id=%I&pageno=1",API_BASE_URL,userID];
```

[image: It look like this after change]

**Update For Image**

Update this code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function in `NewsFeedNew class`

```
NSString *strUrl = [self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].image;
    strUrl = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
    [cell.image sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];
```

Comment: where should add the pageno with url ?

Comment: Hey @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa. I update the answer please check

Comment: it should image on news feed on each cell of table view .Why image is not shown

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa your image not exist on this url. Please contact with you server guy.

[link](http://shoclef.com/Content/Images/Newsfeed/93 Requests.jpg)

Comment: this url is displaying image . http://shoclef.com/Content/Images/Newsfeed/96%20Requests.jpg  ...how to display on each cell of table view

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa I updated the answer please check.

Comment: one last requirement I want when the user the table view is scrolled to last record of the page in table view the circular progress bar should be shown the page number should auto increment along with loading 10 records of next page .Thanks

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa please share you email address. so that I can send you updated source code

Comment: princit@gmail.com is my email address

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa check you email

Comment: in a single scroll view it is loading 10 pages .I want single page should load in scroll view .How to load the single page in scroll view

Answer (score 0):

You need to set tableview `delegate` and `dataSource`.

Also put a break point in `numberOfRowsInSection` method to verify that tableview is set with datasource and delegate.

Comment: I have connected both datasource and delegate but still newsfeed are not shown in table view controller

Comment: is 'numberOfRowsInSection' is getting called?

Comment: Thats the issue...check your datasource array....from that you are displaying data....that will array.count == 0. so there is not data....in array......fetch it and then reload tableview.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to reload data of tableview when you get response - [self.tableView reloadData];

```
-(void)getBuyerSocialPage {
    NSLog(@"getBuyerSocialPage");
    UserDao * profileID = [[DatabaseManager sharedManager]getLoggedInUser];
    ApiManager * manager = [ApiManager sharedManager];
    [manager socialPageWithProfileID:profileID.userID withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL error, NSDictionary *socialPage) {
    //    NSMutableArray * details = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSDictionary * temp in socialPage ) {
            [self.socialPageArray addObject:temp];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        if (!error) {
            self.profileImages=self.socialPageArray;
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code of function but table view still not display news feeds

Answer (score 0):

Few things to debug here,

Your API response might be nil or having error check and log appropriate response.

If the server response is correct then get on the main thread and reload the TableView

Set the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate to self if you haven't done in storyboard.

```
- (void)getBuyerSocialPage {
    NSLog(@"getBuyerSocialPage");
    UserDao *profileID = [[DatabaseManager sharedManager] getLoggedInUser];
    ApiManager *manager = [ApiManager sharedManager];

    __weak BuyerSocialPage *weakSelf = self;
    [manager socialPageWithProfileID:profileID.userID withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL error, NSDictionary *socialPage) { [weak self]
        if (error) {
            NSLog("Error fetching data");
            return;
        }

        for (NSDictionary *temp in socialPage ) {
            [weakSelf.socialPageArray addObject:temp];
        }

        if ([weakSelf.socialPageArray count] > 0) {
            // update UI on the main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                weakSelf.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
     }]
}
```